# Order by eager loaded relation count

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, loading, eager

I have something like this

```
class Item extends Model
{   
    ...
    public function likes() {
    return $this->hasMany('like');
}
...
```

In my controller I load this item like this

```
$items = Item::with([
        ...
        'likes',
        'comments',
        ...
    ])
        ->paginate(10);
```

I need to get likes count and order this list with paginate by this number something like this

```
$items = Item::with([
        ...
        'likes',
        'comments',
        ...
    ])
        ->orderBy(likes->count())
        ->paginate(10);
```

, which obviously is not working. Any tips ? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Just a solution**. But I think there has a **better one**

```
$items = Item::with([
        ...
        'likes',
        'comments',
        ...
    ])
        ->withCount('likes')
        ->orderBy('likes_count','DESC')
        ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this an see if you get your desired output

```
$items = Item::with([
    ...
 'likes'=>function($query){
 $query->selectRaw('likes.*,count(likes.LikeID) as LikesCount')->groupBy('Item.itemID');
 },
    'comments',
    ...
])
    ->orderBy('likes.Likescount','DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```